# How do you Sed to replace the content of a string, instead of just append

Tags: sed

I am trying to modify a file content, which has a specific structure:

```
{
    "name" : "thename",
    "value" : {
                  "a" : "123",
                  "b" : "456"
              }
}
```

I would like to replace the content of a or b; but I can only append to the values, not replace what is in the quotes. For example instead of 123 for a, I would like to put 999.

```
sed -i 's/"a":*/"a": "999"/g' myfile.txt
```

But what I get is

```
{
    "name" : "thename",
    "value" : {
                  "a" : "999" "123",
                  "b" : "456"
              }
}
```

How do I tell sed that I want to replace what is in the quote after that string, and not append to it?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$ sed  's/"a" *:.*/"a" : "999"/' myfile.txt
{
    "name" : "thename",
    "value" : {
                  "a" : "999"
                  "b" : "456"
              }
}
```

The issue is that sed uses *regular expressions*, not *globs*.  As a consequence, `"a":*` matches `"a"` followed by zero or more colons.  Since, in your sample file above, `"a"` is followed by a space, this matches just `"a"`.

In the code above, `"a":*` is replaced with `"a" *:.*/` which matches `"a"` followed by zero or more spaces, followed by a colon, and `.*` which matches everything that follows the colon.  In a regular expression, `.` matches any character and `.*` therefore matches zero or more of any character.  This will match the entirety of the line that follows the colon.

Comment: Thanks! I see why it was not taking the content of what was after the value of a, but the string as literal.